# JSP float left out of alignment by 1 tab when Latin characters followed by CJK

Tags: html, css, jsp, cjk

Float: left combined with a change from Latin to CJK appears to cause a tab to be inserted at the start of the next div so the CJK characters in the label float to the first tab position rather than to the left margin causing the div to be misaligned.

Has anyone experienced  similar problem and found a solution?

Refer: https://jsfiddle.net/90jvnd4v/

html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <label for="data2">aaa :</label>
    <div id="data2" class="child">
      16. 1. 12
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <label for="data2">기한 :</label>
    <div id="data2" class="child">
      16. 2. 13
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="child">
    <label for="data3">기한 :</label>
    <div id="data3" class="child">
      16. 2. 14
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#parent {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

#child {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

label {
  width: 25%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-riht: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you using? This seems to render correctly for me with IE11 and Firefox v.43 on Windows.  Unless what I'm seeing isn't what you intended.  http://postimg.org/image/4cfln81o3/

Comment: Thanks what you are seeing is what was intended. What we see in Chrome and Safari on OSX and Chrome, Firefox (43.0.4), Opera and Edge on W10 is as per http://postimg.org/image/o51nqduqn/ with the third line indented 1 tab. IE 11.0.26 on W10 displays correctly. Interesting that you also get a correct result in Firefox 43 can you advise exact version?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding clear: left to child class and also correcting class references in jsp.

https://jsfiddle.net/davgus/90jvnd4v/10/

```
css
.parent {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
}

.child {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  clear: left;
}

label {
  width: 25%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-riht: 5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
```

jsp
    
    
      
        aaa :
        
          16. 1. 14
        
      
      
        기한 :
        
          16. 2. 13
        
      
        
        기한 :
        
          16. 2. 13